# How can be a Broadcast be "malicious"?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I was going through the docs on Broadcasts and found the following in the [best practices](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html):

> *When you register a receiver, any app can send potentially malicious broadcasts to your app's receiver. There are three ways to limit the
>   broadcasts that your app receives:*

But receiving a broadcast entails receiving an Intent, carrying some data optionally. I was wondering how it can be *malicious* after all?

Answer (score 1):

if you have listeners waiting for a specific signal, from that broadcast, so they can, for example, show a notification, someone can do a *malicious* app that can call that listener and star showing *n* number of notifications and start annoying your user.